# How to set background color(s) of Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate2

[image]

As shown in the above screen shot, the background of code (inside `<? ... ?>`) is different from the area outside PHP code. How can I change the background color of PHP code?

For example, if I change the language to Perl, the color is same inside and outside code:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Themes provide foreground, background and a font style (such as bold) to scopes.

A scope is defined in the languages grammar. These are available for each language under "Bundles" -> "Edit Bundles" -> [Language] -> "Language Grammars" -> [Language].

For your question specifically, you could place the cursor on the php line and press Control + Command + T then search for Copy or Show scope:

```
text.html.php
meta.embedded.block.php
source.php
keyword.operator.class.php
attr.os-version.10.8.5
attr.untitled
```

This shows that the scope you're looking for is called `text.html.php` or `meta.embedded.block.php`. Its probably not `source.php` because that would apply to the entire document.

Now all you need to do is modify the theme, you can tell what your current theme is via "View" -> "Themes", Then edit it with: "Bundles" -> "Edit Bundles" -> Themes -> Themes -> [theme]

I suspect you'd like to add or change something like this, though these colors are horrible.

```
{
  name = 'PHP: Variables Safer Globals';
  scope = 'meta.embedded.block.php';
  settings = {
     foreground = '#00FF00';
     background = '#FF0000';
   };
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! I changed `meta.embedded.block` and `meta.embedded.line` backgrounds and it works globally for all languages.